# Get origin of 'copy' buffer in onPaste

Tags: javascript

Within the handler of `addEventListener('paste', function(e) {});` - is there a way to know where the original clipboard buffer originated ?

So that if the 'copy' that created the buffer that is now being pasted was done on an element in this document I can get that element, and otherwise if it's from some outside source I will get a null etc.

Comment: It's just a text, it has no connection with anything anywhere.

Comment: why dont you track the copy event itself then http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncopy.asp